# Suma acumulada en Vista Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy intentando crear una vista en sql server 2008 para poder obtener los kilos de un producto que varios cargadores entregan, agrupandolos por semana, año y tipo de cargador, así como la cantidad de cargadores que se encargaron de hacer el traslado.

A esto debo agregar una columna que su valor se obtiene de dividir los kilos entre la cantidad de cargadores, una columna de asistencia, y una columna acumulada de los kilos obtenidos.

Lo que me hace falta y no logro hacerlo, es la columna acumulada y mejorar el rendimiento de la vista, ya que al ser una vista no puedo utilizar por ejemplo tablas temporales.

Como tengo la consulta actualmente:

[image: 1]

Como debería quedar la consulta:

[image: 2]

Ejemplo si hubiera más días, de como se calcula el acumulado:
[image: 33]

Si pudieran ayudarme por favor, dejo el siguiente ejemplo:

edit: Se modificó el ejemplo para hacerlo más legible

```
   declare @VMovimientos table(
Anio int,
TipoCargador int,
Semana int,
Kilos decimal(12,2),
Vendedor int,
FechaVenta datetime
)

insert into @VMovimientos(Anio,TipoCargador,Semana,Kilos,Vendedor,FechaVenta)values(2019,1,1,100,1,'01/01/2019')
insert into @VMovimientos(Anio,TipoCargador,Semana,Kilos,Vendedor,FechaVenta)values(2019,2,1,100,1,'01/01/2019')
insert into @VMovimientos(Anio,TipoCargador,Semana,Kilos,Vendedor,FechaVenta)values(2019,1,1,100,2,'03/01/2019')
insert into @VMovimientos(Anio,TipoCargador,Semana,Kilos,Vendedor,FechaVenta)values(2019,2,1,100,3,'04/01/2019')

insert into @VMovimientos(Anio,TipoCargador,Semana,Kilos,Vendedor,FechaVenta)values(2019,1,2,100,1,'05/01/2019')
insert into @VMovimientos(Anio,TipoCargador,Semana,Kilos,Vendedor,FechaVenta)values(2019,2,2,100,1,'07/01/2019')
insert into @VMovimientos(Anio,TipoCargador,Semana,Kilos,Vendedor,FechaVenta)values(2019,1,2,100,2,'05/01/2019')
insert into @VMovimientos(Anio,TipoCargador,Semana,Kilos,Vendedor,FechaVenta)values(2019,2,2,100,3,'05/01/2019')

--select * from @VMovimientos

select a.Anio,a.Semana,b.Asistencia,a.TipoCargador,a.Kilos/b.Asistencia as KHSemana,a.Kilos

from (
    select sum(Kilos) Kilos,TipoCargador,a.Semana,a.Anio
    from @VMovimientos a
    where a.Anio=2019
    group by a.Anio,a.Semana,a.TipoCargador
)a 
inner join (select sum(a.Asistencia) Asistencia,a.Anio,a.Semana,a.TipoCargador
            from (
                select count(distinct(Vendedor)) Asistencia,a.Anio,a.Semana,a.TipoCargador
                from @VMovimientos a
                where a.Anio=2019
                group by a.Anio,a.Semana,a.FechaVenta,a.TipoCargador)a
            group by a.Anio,a.Semana,a.TipoCargador)b on a.Anio=b.Anio and a.Semana=b.Semana and a.TipoCargador=b.TipoCargador
inner join (
    select sum(Kilos) Toneladas,TipoCargador,a.Semana,a.Anio
    from @VMovimientos a
    where a.Anio=2019
    group by a.Anio,a.Semana,a.TipoCargador
)d on a.Anio=d.Anio and a.Semana=d.Semana and a.TipoCargador=d.TipoCargador
order by  a.Anio,a.TipoCargador,a.Semana asc
```

Comment: Qué versión de SQL Server estás usando?

Comment: @Lamak Sql Server 2008, Saludos.

Comment: Ah, bueno, eso complica la cosa bastante (y lo hace más lento también)

Comment: @Lamak, intenté de muchas formas y no logro hacerlo, sobre todo el rendimiento es malísimo, hay casos en los que en un día pueden existir cientos de empleados.

Comment: Este tipo de sumas acumuladas va a tener mal performance en general, a menos que uses alguna característica que está disponible desde SQL Server 2012 en adelante, lamentablemente

Comment: @Lamak para empezar con que logre sacar el acumulado, ya es un gran avance.

Comment: Se debe acumular por vendedor también?, ese dato no está en el ejemplo que pusiste en la pregunta

Comment: @Lamak el acumulado por vendedor no es necesario, solo el acumulado general por cada linea, así como en la imágen. Gracias por tu gran ayuda

Comment: Es que justamente no entiendo cómo debería quedar el resultado viendo los datos que pusiste en el código comparado con las imágenes. Por ejemplo, para el tipoCargador 1, Semana 1, hay 5 vendedores...cuál debería ser el resultado?

Comment: @Lamak edité la imágen, el acumulado se realiza en base a la columna de kilos, para la semana 1 serian 500 kilos y para la segunda serían 1000 kilos que son la suma de la primer semana más la segunda.

Comment: No digo esto por hacer problema, pero sería mejor que la imagen coincida con los datos que pusiste en el código. Hay una asistencia que está en la imagen y no en el código, un vendedor que está en el código y no en la imagen, lo mismo con la fecha de venta. Me hace difícil entender lo que quieres

Comment: @Lamak actualicé el código y el ejemplo para hacerlo más legible, disculpa los inconvenientes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes tratar lo siguiente:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  Anio,
            Semana,
            COUNT(DISTINCT Vendedor) Asistencia,
            TipoCargador,
            SUM(Kilos) Kilos
    FROM @VMovimientos
    GROUP BY Anio,
             Semana,
             TipoCargador
)
SELECT  A.Anio,
        A.Semana,
        A.Asistencia,
        A.TipoCargador,
        A.Kilos/A.Asistencia KHSemana,
        A.Kilos,
        B.KilosAcumulados
FROM CTE A
OUTER APPLY (SELECT SUM(Kilos) KilosAcumulados
             FROM CTE
             WHERE Anio = A.Anio
             AND Semana <= A.Semana
             AND TipoCargador = A.TipoCargador) B
ORDER BY A.Anio,
         A.TipoCargador,
         A.Semana
;
```

Comment: maestro muchas gracias por la enorme ayuda que me has dado, muy agradecido. Saludos.